# GWT UiBinder any way to have dynamic List of Images

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt-widgets

I have a list of say 5 images (imageresources) that i want to add to a panel without having to declare five separate `<img>` tags in my `ui.xml`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@uifield
yourpanel panel`

And you directly add images to that panel.

```
for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++){

Image image =new Image(url);

 .....
...
Panel.add(image);
}
```

Comment: oh i didn't realize Image was a widget. Thank you.